# Only through Christ are we saved?

Tags: grammar, subject-verb-inversion

I know this is biblical, my question is whether this is correct or not. Can it be used in modern day? Example : Much like our lives, only by dedicating undivided attention to our people can we teach ...

Comment: Yes, your construction sounds like it's going to be "correct".  (Can't be sure until it's completed.)  And the construction is not particularly archaic, just a bit convoluted.

Answer (score 0):

It´s a typical construction in which the verb or the modal is mentioned right after the complement that modifies the whole center, and therefore and for the reason of emphasis, is mentioned first.